# Accessing lists / data passing to class from list

Tags: python

I recently was trying to work on a twist to a program I am writing for my first program really. And I have everything working if the user is told to enter some values each time the game runs.

However, I was thinking that it should have a default set of characters that my program/game would use every time. My first goal was to get this to just give every player the same default 3 characters. But eventually this would need to have a have a list expanded of at least the character names.

My trouble comes in that I have taken a if loop that gathered the data each time if they said they have new characters to create, and have tried to modify it to the best of my knowledge to use a list and have it use the position in the loop to get that list number.

Then pass that data down the same paths I had created in the class. But it seems to be just skipping this section which right now I cant see why(I am sure this is a inexperienced moment) Or I am trying to access the list incorrectly? Anyway help on this would be huge, I have included my code below.

I have added commented lines to indicate the  section of code that appears to be skipping.

And clarification I hope on this question is Is the for in loop the right way to solve this issue? And if so am I accessing this the correct way?

```py
print ("Welcome to Chose your own adventure python edition")
print ("")


players = []

playerCharacters = []

def playerNames():
    playerNum = int(input("How many players are playing? "))
    if playerNum > 4:
        print("I am sorry, unfortunately only four players are permitted.")

        return


    for playerId in range(playerNum):

        newPlayerName = input(f"What is player {playerId + 1}'s name?")
        players.append(newPlayerName)
    
    print(f"Welcome: {' & '.join(players)}!")


def characters():
    charAmount = 3

    for index, player in enumerate(players):

        playerCreate = input("{} (player {}), do you have a character to create. (y/n)".format(
            player, str(index+1)))
        if playerCreate.lower() =="y":
            charAmount = int(input("How many characters does this player begin the game with?"))
            
            for x in range(0,(charAmount)):
                getCharName = input("Enter Next Char name ")
                getCharDice = input("Please enter the number of dice this char will use. ")
                getCharRole = input("Please enter the villagers role. ")

                charData = {
                    "name": getCharName,
                    "diceCount": getCharDice,
                    "role": getCharRole,
                    "playerName": player
                }
                
                newCharacter = Character(characterData=charData)
                newCharacter.printSummary()
                playerCharacters.append(newCharacter)
            

        if playerCreate.lower() == "n":
            defaultCapture = input("Would you like to begin with the default charatures. (y/n)?" )
        
            if defaultCapture.lower() == "y":
            
                ###Beginning of skipped code         
                for x in range (0,3):
                    
                    DefaultCharName = ["Bob", "Sally", "Tommy"]
                    DefaultDiceCount = 1
                    DefaultRole = ['Builder', "Recruiter" , "Nothing"]



                    charData = {
                        "name": DefaultCharName(x),
                        "diceCount": DefaultDiceCount,
                        "role": DefaultRole(x),
                        "playerName": player
                    }

                    DefaultCharacters = Character(characterData=charData)
                    DefaultCharacters.printSummary()
                    playerCharacters.append(DefaultCharacters)
                    ###End of skipped section

                    if defaultCapture.lower == "n":
                        print("Well it looks as though you dont really want to play.")    
                        continue

                    print("Summary ==========================")
                    for player in playerCharacters:
                        print("{characterName} Controlled by {playerName}".format(
                            playerName=player.playerName,
                            characterName=player.name ))
                    return

class Character:
    
    name = "default name"
    playerName = "john/jane doe"
    diceCount = "1"
    role = "vanillaPaste"

    def __init__(self, characterData):
        
        self.playerName = characterData['playerName']
        self.role = characterData['role']
        self.diceCount = characterData['diceCount']
        self.name = characterData['name']

    def printSummary(self):
        print("{player} summary: \r\n \r\nCharacters:\r\nName: {characterName} \r\nDice: {dice} \r\nRole: {role} \r\n"
                .format(
                    characterName=self.name, 
                    player=self.playerName,
                    dice=self.diceCount,
                    role=self.role
                  );


playerNames()
characters()
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry if this sounds harsh, but from the wall of text and the code, there is no way to find out what you are asking for, what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is. You need to be precise and include important information like error messages if you hope to get an answer that will actually help you. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: Not sure which section is skipping. Could you please add a comment against that section?

Comment: try to check the indentation of the for loop and when you enter something, do not have spaces. You should ude defaultCapture.lower().split =="y" or defaultCapture.lower().split.contains("y"). Add the brackets().

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick response on this matter, and massive apologies for these issues. I have hopefully be able to address them a bit more. I have added a beginning of the skipped comment line and an ending of the comment line. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

While your code is, like the comments say, a little too long for a minimal SO question, in this case it's an easy fix.

Just before your "start of skipped section", you have

```
if defaultCapture.lower == "y":
```

which is missing the parentheses to actually call `.lower()`, to lower-case the string. (Comparing a function to a string would always be false.)

That expression should be

```
if defaultCapture.lower() == "y":
```

Comment: OH man thanks a huge bunch, that has now given me another error. But that it is giving me an error. And I'm sorry again for the wall of code did not really know how to divide it down given data flowing all over the place.Now to give do a bit more research on how to resolve this error.

Comment: There are other syntax errors in your code. Look into using an IDE that will help you along, such as PyCharm (the free Community Edition is fine).

Comment: Yes, I have been coding it on repl.it. I have in the past used sublime3 to write code I was using for small program overrides in the program Nuke. But I am trying this time around to get a better understanding of the code, as a base code not limited by the usage that Nuke was doing it as.(Also this allowed me to get syntax error which I have found the answer for here on SO.) Anyway thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! For the heck of it, here's a refactoring of your code into multiple functions to reduce nesting and use of global variables. https://gist.github.com/akx/6ee8cf9110a6f7af38d4a7f2f980d7d5

Comment: That's cool. And it just goes to show I have so much more to learn. I will try and use read over this and learn more from it.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the indentation of the for loop and when you enter something, do not have spaces. You should use

```
 defaultCapture.lower().split =="y"
```

OR

```
defaultCapture.lower().split.contains("y")// Add the brackets()
```